# DataGridView mousewheel scrolling stopped working

Tags: c#, datagridview, scroll, mousewheel

I have a DataGridView in my app and I can't scroll it using the mousewheel. It used to work fine before. I'm not sure what I have done to cause this because I only noticed it recently after I had made multiple changes to the code.

I'm not posting any code because there are more than 2k lines and I'm not sure where the error could possibly be.

Any ideas what might have caused this? If you need any code I can edit the question afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here's the answer of the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11209059/datagridview-mouse-wheel-scrolling-stoped-working/11244708#11244708)

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
<div style="vertical-align: top; height: 152px; overflow:auto;width:800px;">
```

Your grid view control

```
</div>
```

Comment: It's a C# desktop application! Thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

The mousewheel support for a DataGridView is buggy.

The bugs mean that renders are frequently corrupted and can cause occasional crashing.

I would imagine that someone else in your team disabled mousewheel support for the DataGridView as a bugfix.

This is usually done by manually implimenting the Mousewheel with a line that begins with the following:

```
    MyDataGridView.MouseWheel += new MouseEventHandler(...
```

Commenting out that line will reenable the Mousewheel support, but I would not advise it.