# DataGridView mouse wheel scrolling stopped working

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a DataGridView in my app and I can't scroll it using the mousewheel. It used to work fine before. I'm not sure what I have done to cause this because I only noticed it recently after I had made multiple changes to the code.

I'm not posting any code because there are more than 2k lines and I'm not sure where the error could possibly be.

Any ideas what might have caused this? If you need any code I can edit the question afterwards.

Comment: The mouse wheel will only scroll the grid if the grid has focus. Try clicking on one of the cells in the grid before using the scroll wheel.

Comment: Have you accidentally added an EventHandler for the MouseWheel event that's intercepting the event?

Comment: Thanks, it's the focus that is moved when I click on a cell.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Almost certainly the problem occurs because the DataGridView has lost focus. This can be because another control on your form demands focus or your form is set by default to give a different control focus.

You can force the DataGridView to have focus. If you want to emulate the standard Microsoft Windows behavior of enabling mouse wheel scroll when the mouse is hovering over the control then just use the code below.

```
private void SettingsGrid_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     dataGridView1.Focus();
}
```

If you want to scroll the grid regardless of what control has focus then the code will be similar to above with a little beak of tweaking.

Comment: That's it! Thanks. It switches focus to a textbox when clicked on. Now I need to figure out how to keep the switching of focus to the textbox and being able to scroll the dataGridView.